# Downsides of predicting sentiment using a dictionary-based sentiment

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, nlp

I have a dataset of 30K tweets in English and I am using a sentiment-based dictionary/lexicon of 9K unique words that classifies each word into either positive or negative. However, some tweets have a low number of recognized words by the dictionary (e.g. a tweet with 70 words only had 3 words recognized by the sentiment dictionary), which means I would be predicting sentiment for an entire tweet based on only 3 words or 4% of total words in the tweet.

I have noticed that there are several methods to deal with practical issues like the one above, and was wondering if it's best to exclude tweets based on either of the following criteria:

1- Identify a specific minimum of recognized words by the dictionary and drop any below that threshold, versus

2- Use a proportion or % of minimum recognized words such as 10%, and drop all tweets where the dictionary recognizes less than that figure?

I believe both techniques from the literature have their downsides but I lean towards the latter method.